# Using a function to return a value on a plotLine [HighCharts]

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I want to return a value in form of a plotLine in my chart.

```
plotLines: [{
                  color: 'red',
                  value: resp.data.res0.map(function(a){
                    sum += parseInt(a[1]);
                    return sum;
                  }),
                  width: '1',
                  zIndex: 2
                }]
              },
```

The value of sum here is not that important, just that it is a number. But I am not sure how I am supposed to render it to the chart. The response in a[1] is JSON.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Is it your goal for `value` to end up with the value that is the sum of all the `a[1]`s in `resp.data.res0`?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to initialize `value` with the sum of all the `a[1]`s in `resp.data.res0`, then you're looking for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), not `map`:

```
value: resp.data.res0.reduce(function(sum, a){
    return sum + parseInt(a[1]);
}, 0)
```

In the two-argument form I used above, `reduce` calls the callback once for each entry in the array, passing the previous sum and the array element. The return value of the callback is the new sum. The sum is initialized with `0` (the second argument).

Example:

```js
var res0 = [
  [undefined, "1"],
  [undefined, "2"],
  [undefined, "3"],
  [undefined, "4"]
];
var value = res0.reduce(function(sum, a) {
  return sum + parseInt(a[1]);
}, 0);
document.body.innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: When i use console.log(sum) in the function i do get values, but nothing gets rendered in the chart, does a return statement not work to give a value to plotLines[]? Also, the sum gets calculated 3 times because thats how many responses there is, how can i get the last/final value of sum?

Comment: @Daniel: The code above produces **one** sum, the sum of the values of the `1` property of the elements in the `res0` array. So in the above, the `reduce` call returns 10, because 1+2+3+4 = 10.

Comment: Slight oversight. My JSON response looks like this

{[2016-02-11], [5]}, where a[0] is a date, and a[1] contains the values I want to calculate.